# IIS Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-authentication

I have a local domain. Also we have a web site that authorizes user based on his domain account. So, when I log in into computer using domain account and open the browser I am already authorized on that web site.

I don't have access to that website, and I need to implement this feature in my own website.

I have

- 192.168.1.235 - IIS with my web site and Domain Controller
- 192.168.1.233 - test domain machine

I have enabled Windows authentication in IIS settings. It works great when I open 192.168.1.235 from 192.168.1.235. But when I try to open 192.168.1.235 from 192.168.1.233 Internet Explorer pops login/password authorization form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are hundreds upon hundreds of tutorials on setting up websites that use Windows Authentication.  I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: the problem is - it asks for domain credentials and don't login me without them.

Comment: are you using a browser with Integrated Windows Authentication (IE) enabled?

Comment: also stop using authorization when you mean authentication. login is Authentication. Authorization is how you determine whether a logged in user is capable of taking a specific action.

Comment: What have you tried already? From the test machine: Can you ping the server? Reach shared folders on it? Can you reach the domain's Netlogon folder (etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want IIS 7.5 Integrated Security with no prompt for credentials
you need to make these steps:

If you try to configure an IIS site to use integrated security and still get the prompt for credentials, here are few key things to validate.

First, make sure that Anonymous Authentication is turned OFF for the site.

Second, enable integrated security in Interner Explorer (Options/Advanced and checkin the “Enable Integrated Windows Authentication” option).

**Third, add your website to Local Intranet zone and select at least “Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone” option under Options/Security Settings/Local intranet/Custom level).**

Fourth, make sure the user and application server are in the same domain.